# Como eliminar valores em uma coluna de texto de um arquivo csv no R?

Tags: r

Eu estou aprendendo R e preciso de ajuda com arquivos CSV. Eu consigo fazer a leitura do arquivo, mas preciso executar operações com algumas colunas:

**O arquivo está assim:**

```
1   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:326463633336323 off_product_id:613665646663346  quantity:1  price:229.0 customer_id:null}
2   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:333331346330323 off_product_id:343739666265353  quantity:1  price:179.0 customer_id:null}
3   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:393461383633336 off_product_id:373034633762613  quantity:1  price:269.0 customer_id:null}
4   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:616531626536373 off_product_id:343634373062363  quantity:1  price:29.0  customer_id:null}
5   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:626462353638383 off_product_id:616339353035393  quantity:1  price:459.0 customer_id:null}
6   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:653363623539323 off_product_id:346165376638356  quantity:1  price:369.0 customer_id:null}
```

**Mas eu quero deixar desta forma:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione a forma que você deixar diretamente à pergunta. (transcreva a imagem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dados <- read.table(text = 
  "1   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:326463633336323 off_product_id:613665646663346  quantity:1  price:229.0 customer_id:null}
   2   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:333331346330323 off_product_id:343739666265353  quantity:1  price:179.0 customer_id:null}
   3   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:393461383633336 off_product_id:373034633762613  quantity:1  price:269.0 customer_id:null}
   4   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:616531626536373 off_product_id:343634373062363  quantity:1  price:29.0  customer_id:null}
   5   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:626462353638383 off_product_id:616339353035393  quantity:1  price:459.0 customer_id:null}
   6   {date:2018-08-01    state:RN    store_id:3162633    sale_id:653363623539323 off_product_id:346165376638356  quantity:1  price:369.0 customer_id:null}",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Remove a primeira coluna (desnecessária)
dados <- dados[, !(names(dados) %in% "V1")]

# Remove os colchetes
dados[] <- lapply(dados, gsub, pattern = "\\{|\\}", replacement = "")

# Pega os nomes das colunas
colnames(dados) <- gsub(":.*$", "", dados[1,])

# Remove caracteres até ":"
dados[] <- lapply(dados, gsub, pattern = ".*:", replacement = "")


> dados
        date state store_id         sale_id  off_product_id quantity price customer_id
1 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 326463633336323 613665646663346        1 229.0        null
2 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 333331346330323 343739666265353        1 179.0        null
3 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 393461383633336 373034633762613        1 269.0        null
4 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 616531626536373 343634373062363        1  29.0        null
5 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 626462353638383 616339353035393        1 459.0        null
6 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 653363623539323 346165376638356        1 369.0        null
```

Os dados estarão todos no formato *character*; você terá o trabalho adicional de converter para os formatos adequados.

### Arquivo JSON

Pela aparência dos seus dados brutos, você tem um arquivo JSON que foi erroneamente salvo como CSV. Se é esse caso e é você quem está capturando os dados, corrija o script para salvar no formato json. A leitura pode ser feita de maneira simples e preservando os formatos com o pacote `jsonlite`:

```
library(jsonlite)

dados.json <- '[{"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":326463633336323,"off_product_id":613665646663346,"quantity":1,"price":229.0,"customer_id":"null"},
                {"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":333331346330323,"off_product_id":343739666265353,"quantity":1,"price":179.0,"customer_id":"null"},
                {"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":393461383633336,"off_product_id":373034633762613,"quantity":1,"price":269.0,"customer_id":"null"},
                {"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":616531626536373,"off_product_id":343634373062363,"quantity":1,"price":29.0,"customer_id":"null"},
                {"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":626462353638383,"off_product_id":616339353035393,"quantity":1,"price":459.0,"customer_id":"null"},
                {"date":"2018-08-01","state":"RN","store_id":3162633,"sale_id":653363623539323,"off_product_id":346165376638356,"quantity":1,"price":369.0,"customer_id":"null"}]'

dados <- fromJSON(dados.json)


> dados
        date state store_id      sale_id off_product_id quantity price customer_id
1 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 3.264636e+14   6.136656e+14        1   229        null
2 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 3.333313e+14   3.437397e+14        1   179        null
3 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 3.934614e+14   3.730346e+14        1   269        null
4 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 6.165316e+14   3.436344e+14        1    29        null
5 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 6.264624e+14   6.163394e+14        1   459        null
6 2018-08-01    RN  3162633 6.533636e+14   3.461654e+14        1   369        null

> str(dados)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  8 variables:
$ date          : chr  "2018-08-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-08-01" ...
$ state         : chr  "RN" "RN" "RN" "RN" ...
$ store_id      : int  3162633 3162633 3162633 3162633 3162633 3162633
$ sale_id       : num  3.26e+14 3.33e+14 3.93e+14 6.17e+14 6.26e+14 ...
$ off_product_id: num  6.14e+14 3.44e+14 3.73e+14 3.44e+14 6.16e+14 ...
$ quantity      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1
$ price         : num  229 179 269 29 459 369
$ customer_id   : chr  "null" "null" "null" "null" ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou muito